# Lost Permission of Home Directory

Tags: permissions, home-directory, users, ubuntu-tweak

I recently messed up my Ubuntu Setup, so I re-installed and choose to use my existing Home directory .

Now I cannot launch Ubuntu-Tweak as myself, but am able to do so with `sudo` command.

Any help will be appreciated.

Also as a result it seems my chrome has not yet updated to the new extensions I installed from other machines.

The Tweak log on `/home/sarvesh/.config/ubuntu-tweak/*.log` is empty

Also when I command users, I see my username three times.

[image]

Comment: I also cannot seem to get rid of the Update Notification, clicking on preferences or any option doesnt do anything, but still works when access from synaptic

Comment: Since you reinstalled, how did you reuse your existing home folder?

Comment: just plain use as ext4 and mouunt as /home/ without formatting